# SNMP communication failure

Tags: ubuntu, snmp, snmpd

I've just setup SNMP on a ubuntu server [12.04.4 LTS] for monitoring and I have been fighting this thing for 8 days straight with NO LUCK! I'm sure I have SNMP installed and configured correctly, however when trying to SNMP walk this server from another machine, I get a timeout response. I'm using version 2c in my snmpwalk command and I know I'm using the correct string 'public'. There are not firewalls or firewall rules in between the two. Here is my snmpd.conf file [ **For security reasons, I have replaced my origanl IP with X's**]

```
####### sec.name source               community
com2sec permitted 127.0.0.1             public     # Localhost
com2sec permitted xx xx.xx.xxxx         public     # Home Insight Connection
############### sec.model sec.name
group   roGroup v1      permitted
group   roGroup v2c     permitted

############### incl/excl subtree
view    all     included  .1

############### ctx sec.model sec.level   prefix read write notify

access  roGroup ""  any       noauth      exact  all  none  none
```

Here is my /etc/default/snmpd file

```
# This file controls the activity of snmpd and snmptrapd

# Don't load any MIBs by default.
# You might comment this lines once you have the MIBs downloaded.
export MIBS=

# snmpd control (yes means start daemon).
SNMPDRUN=yes

# snmpd options (use syslog, close stdin/out/err).

SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid'

# snmptrapd control (yes means start daemon).  As of net-snmp version
# 5.0, master agentx support must be enabled in snmpd before snmptrapd
# can be run.  See snmpd.conf(5) for how to do this.
TRAPDRUN=no

# snmptrapd options (use syslog).
TRAPDOPTS='-Lsd -p /var/run/snmptrapd.pid'

# create symlink on Debian legacy location to official RFC path
SNMPDCOMPAT=yes
```

My IPTABLE rules are empty. I even stopped the service with no luck

```
root@dws411:/etc/default# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I event checkedthe host.allow and host.deny files in the /etc/ directory. Both of these files are empty as well. I SURELY hope someone can help me out on this. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Can you snoop the traffic on the agent side, to verify that the request packets are reaching it? Wireshark, tcpdump or similar tools can do it. Also, please provide the exact syntax you used when making the request.

Comment: I was able to tail -f the daemon.log log file filtering it down to the syslog entries. I see in real time that my SNMP requests are hitting the server. The SNMP snytax I'm using is **snmpwalk -v 2c -c public IP_Address system.** . I was able to spend quite a bit of time on this last night. I think I just about got it narrowed down and will continue to work on it this evening. I will update this thread once I have an update.

Answer (score 0):

agentaddress  udp:161
add this in snmpd.conf

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).